# Expression result unused — what's wrong with my C code?

Tags: c, cs50

I making a program which runs a "greedy" algorithm — one which asks for an input value of change owed and returns the minimum amount of coins required to return that change while using as few coins as possible. The only coins which can be used are the quarter, dime, nickel and penny. Please take a look at my code and tell me how I could fix the error being displayed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    float change;
    int counter;
    counter = 0;
    do 
    {
        printf("Please imput how much change is owed: ");
        change = GetFloat();
    }
    while (change<=0); 
    int centv;
    {
        centv = round(change*100);
    }

    int quarter, dime, nickel, penny;
    quarter= 25;
    dime= 10;
    nickel= 5;
    penny= 1;

    {
        while( centv>=quarter )
            {       
                (centv-25);
                counter++;  
            }

        while( centv>=dime )  
            {                
                (centv-10);
                counter++;
            }        
        while( centv>=nickel )
            {            
                (centv-5);
                counter++;
            }
        while( centv>=penny)
            {
                (centv-1);
                counter++;
            }   

        if(centv == 0)
            {
                printf("%i \n", counter);
            }
    }
}
```

The errors I'm getting are with the lines `(centv-25)`, `(centv-10)`, `(centv-5)` and `(cent-1)`.

The error message is "expression result unused" for all of them.
How do I fix this?

Comment: An expression like `(centv-25)` produces a value. But because you don't assign that value to a variable, it's unused. The compiler might delete that code if it has not side effects.

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to change the value of `centv`, you need something like `centv = centv - 25;`

`centv - 25` should be replaced with `centv = centv - 25`, and similarly for the other lines.

Comment: I added that to my code and I'm still getting the same error message. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you do it for all of them or just for the quarter case?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in Jens's comment, `(centv-25)` computes the value of centv - 25 but then does nothing with it.  Simarly with `(centv-10)`, `(centv-5)`, and `(centv-1)`.  In each of the four cases, you need to assign the result of the subtraction to `centv`.

```
centv = centv-25;
...
centv = centv-10;
...
centv = centv-5;
...
centv = centv-1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might intend to subtract `25`, etc. from `centv`. Replace the expressions by a [*compound assignment*](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.2):

```
centv -= 25;

etc.
```